# Some values are nil (which were set) when parsing JSON in Ruby using the "json" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

when I parse the following json in my rails console then the contact_person_id is nil even it was "c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a". I am using the normal "json" gem. I tried to use some other library for example "yajl_ruby" but then something other broke. has anybody an idea why this happens?

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode '{"_id":"a042b081278fc535f50fd3f4ea695848","_rev":"7-435d6ef891d2d354a7233674c483194b","created_at":"2011-12-12T18:39:19Z","updated_at":"2011-12-12T22:34:35Z","contact_person_id":"c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a","first_person_in_authority_id":null,"second_person_in_authority_id":null,"name":"","street":"","postcode":"","city":"","ruby_class":"Community"}'

=> #<Community _id: "a042b081278fc535f50fd3f4ea695848", _rev: "7-435d6ef891d2d354a7233674c483194b", created_at: Mon, 12 Dec 2011 18:39:19 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 12 Dec 2011 22:34:35 UTC +00:00, contact_person_id: nil, first_person_in_authority_id: nil, second_person_in_authority_id: nil, name: "", street: "", postcode: "", city: "", regional_chirch: nil, deanery: nil, chirch_district: nil, state: nil, urban_district: nil, county: nil, administrative_district: nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm this problem with the following versions:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.0.0]
activesupport (3.1.3)
```

I used the following snippet:

```
irb(main):003:0> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode '{"_id":"a042b081278fc535f50fd3f4ea695848","_rev":"7-435d6ef891d2d354a7233674c483194b","created_at":"2011-12-12T18:39:19Z","updated_at":"2011-12-12T22:34:35Z","contact_person_id":"c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a","first_person_in_authority_id":null,"second_person_in_authority_id":null,"name":"","street":"","postcode":"","city":"","ruby_class":"Community"}'
=> {"city"=>"", "name"=>"", "created_at"=>"2011-12-12T18:39:19Z", "postcode"=>"", "first_person_in_authority_id"=>nil, "_rev"=>"7-435d6ef891d2d354a7233674c483194b", "updated_at"=>"2011-12-12T22:34:35Z", "_id"=>"a042b081278fc535f50fd3f4ea695848", "street"=>"", "contact_person_id"=>"c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a", "second_person_in_authority_id"=>nil, "ruby_class"=>"Community"}
irb(main):004:0> _['contact_person_id']
=> "c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a"
```

I think the problem lies within your codebase i.e. the `Community` model.
Things to check:

- Is there some `after_initialization` hook?
- Is there a custom `contact_person_id=` setter?
- Is `contact_person` a relation that must exist with the id `c221c0f96670db455a174f1f30ffef1a`?

Without any further information, I'm sorry that I cannot give you a better answer.